# XML variable not populated in c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Here is a piece of code where i am trying to embed a list of integers into an XML.

```
function(long[] Idlist)
{
XDocument inputXML = new XDocument(
             new XElement("Ids",
                       from wp in Idlist
                        select new XElement("element")));
}
```

I have FOUR values in my IdList[20,30,40,50] but still the input xml doesnt populate any values.

AND the inputXML is populated like this :

```
<Ids>
  <element/>
  <element/>
  <element/>
  <element/>
</Ids>
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I suggest you populate the XAML with elements that have values, instead of empty elements like `new XElement("element")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The values will be fetched from the Idlist i believe. Should it not populate the XML ? Can you show an example please.

Comment: Why do you think it knows what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks like:

```
from wp in Idlist
select new XElement("element")
```

You aren't using any data from your `Idlist` to feed into the `XElement`.

you've used [this constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb292758(v=vs.110).aspx) which creates an empty element with the name you've provided.

Try using [the correct constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341343(v=vs.110).aspx) that allows you to pass in a value for the `XElement` as well as a name.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has no way of knowing that you want `wp` to be included in the XML somehow. If you want something to happen, you have to ask nicely.

```
XDocument inputXML = new XDocument(
    new XElement("Ids",
        from wp in Idlist
        //  XElement has another constructor which takes a second 
        //  parameter, and uses that as the content of the element.
        select new XElement("element", wp)
        ));
```

XML

```
<Ids>
  <element>20</element>
  <element>30</element>
  <element>40</element>
  <element>50</element>
</Ids>
```

Answer (score -1):

In VB .Net this would work

```
    Dim xe As XElement = <Ids></Ids>
    Dim IdList As New List(Of Integer) From {20, 30, 40, 50}
    For Each id As Integer In IdList
        Dim els As XElement = <element><%= id %></element>
        xe.Add(New XElement(els))
    Next
```